# Citation count from a book published by a mid-size publisher

Tags: citations, thesis, publishers

My PhD dissertation has been published years ago as a book by a mid-size publisher and it is partially available on google books. However, the pages of the reference section are hidden, which means that no bibliographic metric can capture the references and hence no citation count.

Since I cited all my published papers in the dissertation, it would make sense to make these citations (approx. 15) counted but I am not allowed to publish an electronic post-print of the dissertation.

Is there any way to make these citations counted?

Comment: Harumpf. Self-citations are not really citations....

Comment: @DeboraWeber-Wulff. Why not? They are not when occur arbitrarily. Often, a few self-citations help to increase the visibility of papers.

Comment: Where do you want them to be counted? Try contacting that organization.

Comment: @Younes, because self-citations are a bit like patting yourself on the back. Of course you know your material, but the important thing is that others cite your work - either positively or negatively. When I was a grad student we calculated the self-citation index of various authors - the more self-citations, the less well-founded the work seemed.....

Comment: @DeboraWeber-Wulff I cannot agree more but the dissertation is built based on these papers and this is true for all researchers without exception. I also discourage self-citation but in this case, they are well and legitimately cited. On the other side, there are more than 100 references in the dissertation, whose citations are not counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Major publishers deposit citations as openly available metadata, often at *CrossRef*. You could ask your publisher to do so -- refer to CrossRef's article ["Adding references to your metadata record"](https://www.crossref.org/documentation/metadata-stewardship/maintaining-your-metadata/add-references/).

These metadata will usually be picked up by bibliographic databases such as *Web of Science*, *Scopus*, or *Dimensions*. (I am not sure about *Google Scholar* though, as GS seems to collect citation data via "webcrawling" and not necessarily via the CrossRef API, but I might be wrong.)

If your publisher does not have the capacity to deposit such metadata, then you could do it yourself by depositing the references at *CROCI*, or the *Crowdsourced Open Citations Index*. Some technical skills might be required for that, see [this page](https://opencitations.net/index/croci) for more information.